# Visual Basic word table bold / not bold

Tags: vb.net, csv

I'm currently reading CSV files and putting them into a word document. Now my question is if its possible to write the text in the cell both bold and the entry from the csv not bold. I know the code below puts all the info in the cell on not bold but this may show what I want.

```
oTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Font.Bold = True
oTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Vurnerability description: "
oTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Font.Bold = False
oTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text += openvasCSV(i)(9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty disgusting, but it works. I couldn't avoid using Select though, would love to see a solution where it is not needed.

```
oTable.Cell(2, 1).Select
Selection.Font.Bold = True
Selection.TypeText "üüü"
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.Font.Bold = False
Selection.TypeText "öööö"
```

The key is using `.Font`, not `.Range`, and setting the `Bold` property for the current run only.

Comment: First of all thanks for your comment. Im not sure why but i think you are using a different programming language then me becuase there was no way i could use this code in som sort.

Comment: This is MS Word VBA. Did it produce an error message or anything? Are you in Word? If you are for example in Excel, the `Selection` will mean something else, so you will need to specify the Word object.

Comment: I'm programming in Visual Basic itself.  https://i.imgur.com/tCMFbyM.png

Comment: Aaaah! Then why don't you use the proper tags?... Remove _VBA_, remove _cell_ and _bold_, use **VB.net**, maybe a version too, use the name of the package you are using, like **Open XML SDK**... Of course you get answer in a different language if you specify the tags wrong. :)

Comment: Still, something similar should work if you precede the `Selection` with your WordObject.

Comment: Sorry about that i'm kinda new to coding :)